# Making an array with input from a textFile using BufferedReader

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I am making a file read a text file with recipes info and format it. To do so I am using a loop however I got a problem with the reading part. This is a sample of one recipe in the text file I am using as input:

```
"id": 44330 
"cuisine": "indian"
"ingredients": 
"butter"
"peanut butter"
"chuck"
"curry powder"
"unsalted dry roast peanuts"
"coconut milk"
"brown sugar"
```

And this is my code that is supposed to go through each element and store it in an array. My problem is that I think I need to make another array of just the ingredients since each recipe sample will have a different number of ingredients. I am not sure how to approach this issue or how to code the unspecified array:

```
while (currentLine != null) {

    String[] RecipeId = currentLine.split("\\s+");
    String idName = RecipeId[0];
    int id = Integer.valueOf(RecipeId[1]);
    String cuisine = RecipeId[2];
    String cuisinetype = RecipeId[3];
    String[] ingredientsList = currentLine.split("\\s+");
    String ingredientOne = ingredientsList[];


    recipesFormat.add(new Student(idName, id,cuisine,cuisinetype));
    recipesIngredients.add(new Ingredients(ingredientsList));
}
```

Comment: If I'm understand correctly you're split `currentLine` and the get index 0 and 1 BUT you're not always have index 1.... **Btw** I think it's recommended to use `json` or even `xml`...

Comment: (related: [Reading recipe lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577085/java-trouble-reading-multiple-lines-of-a-text-file).)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Receipt {

    private int id;
    private String cuisine;
    private ArrayList<String> ingredients;

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getCuisine() { return cuisine; }
    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) { this.cuisine = cuisine; }
    public ArrayList<String> getIngredients() { return ingredients; }
    public void setIngredients(ArrayList<String> ingredients) { this.ingredients = ingredients; }

}

public List<Receipt> readReceipts() {

    List<Receipt> receipts = new ArrayList<>();
    Receipt receipt = null;

    try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/input.txt")))) {

        String line;
        while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {

            // new receipt
            if(line.startsWith("\"id\":")) {

                // add old
                if(receipt != null)
                    receipts.add(receipt);

                receipt = new Receipt();

                receipt.setId(Integer.valueOf(line.split(":\\s*")[1].trim()));
                line = r.readLine();
                receipt.setCuisine(line.split(":\\s*")[1].replaceAll("\"", "").trim());
                line = r.readLine(); // skip this line
                receipt.setIngredients(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            else {
                receipt.getIngredients().add(line.replaceAll("\"", ""));
            }

        }

        // last fetched receipt
        receipts.add(receipt);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return receipts;

}
```